# In Team Foundation Server, How does one fork a project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

My question in self explanatory. Is it possible to fork a project in team foundation server, and how would I go about forking a project in TFS if it is possible?

Comment: Yes you can. Instructions for completing this task can be found here:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181425(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181425%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you mean tfs's "branch" when you say "fork". You can do it either from visual studio or from command line. In VS, in source control explorer select folder and from context menu choose "branch".

Comment: I have continued my search after this question. It came across my superior meant to branch his project. I was mighty confused as to why he used the term fork it seems. Marking yours as solution

Comment: @EonRustedduPlessis You can only branch Source Code, not a Project (Work Items, Queries, Reports, etc.) though. Those must be copied into the new one.

Comment: Forking and branching isn't the same!
Branching means making a new copy for a new feature and experiments which will be merged to the master later. Forking means making a copy for an independent project.

Comment: Interesting point. In TFS I think that branch command is really the only implementation of fork (and branch) you have